# Is it safe to use the reference result of a function within an anonymous function which is used as the parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-function

Is it safe to use the reference result of a function within an anonymous function which is used as the parameter?

Following is a simplified example:

```
    ClassA result = null;
    result = instanceA.FunctionA(() => {
        DoSomething();
        if (result != null)
            result.foo();
    };
```

Here DoSomething() cost some in my project(unity animation), so when result.foo() is called, it's actually several seconds after. I tested this code in my project which works now, but I wonder is it a safe design? Becuase if I write like this it won't compile.

```
    ClassA result = instanceA.FunctionA(() => {
        DoSomething();
        if (result != null)
            result.foo();
    };
```

The compiler gives error " Cannot use local variable 'result' before it is declared".

I tested in another simplified example, where the DoSomthing() won't cost any time. In this way the codes seems don't work, because the I can see "1" printed in the console, but can't find "2 x.a = ".

```
class ResultClass
{
    public int a;
}
public void FunctionA()
{
    ResultClass x = default;
    x = TestB(()=>{
        x.a += 200;
        print("2 x.a = " + x.a);
        
    });
}

ResultClass TestB(Action handler)
{
    var a = new ResultClass();
    a.a = 100;
    print("1");
    return a;
}
```

=========New Edit with more explanation==========

Thanks all for your help and opinion! @Jonas Høgh pointed out I never called handler in TestB. Sorry about this mistake and it's a bad example. I tried to call "handler.?Invoke()" right after print("1"), but it raied "NullReferenceException". However it worked in my real project, because it's an over simplified and kinda wrong example. I'll explain with more details and just leave the bad example here unchanged.

In my real project, the TestB has a animation list mechanism, which will add the handler(the anonymous function) into a queue, and will be invoked say several seconds later. I guess that's why when it's called, it won't raise NullReferenceException. And in the first part of codes, the DoSomething() is also managed by the animation list mechanism.

With all your help and some examples with working codes from @JohnLBevan and @vc 74 (thanks a lot!), I cleared my thought, and figured out my real question is this: Is it OK to use directly the referenced result in the anonymous function(shown in both of my example codes), instead of passing the result as parameter into the anonymous function as what both of you did in your example codes?

Comment: maybe just me, but what is "safe" supposed to mean?

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `result` within your anonymous function?  i.e. Before you call your function you set it to null, then later (within your function) you check whether it's not null; but at that check / in the example you provided, it will always be null.

Comment: @JohnLBevan The result is assigned by FuntionA.

Comment: But FunctionA is calling your anonymous function (or at least, I assume it is as it's taking it as an argument), and isn't passing `result` as a parameter to it.  Could you give an example to better illustrate what's going on in FunctionA / how it's affecting the value.  To help, assume that `ClasssA` is `string` and have the functions amend this value at each step and include a `Debug.WriteLine(result);` in each stage to help show what's going on.

Comment: In your second example, testb never calls handler…

Comment: judging from your edit and the obvious mistake @JonasHøgh already pointed out, I would suggest take a deep breath figure out a coherent demo, showing your issue and than come back to ask

Comment: and No, `x` will not be set before calling `handler` - because `TestB` will need to call `handler` before it returns a value

Comment: Here's a tweaked version of your example which is runnable.  I'm not sure if this does what you'd expect it to do, but hope that it helps: https://dotnetfiddle.net/towPcj

Comment: What's the point of the `if (result != null) result.foo();`? You know that the `result` is going to be `null`, so the `result.foo()` won't be invoked. It looks like dead code to me. What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I can't just add a handler?.Invoke() into the example codes, because that's a wrong simplification. I've edited the question with more explanation. In my real project I have a very complex animation list to make sure the handler will be invoked after several seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you check for null to account for the case where the variable is used before the method returns, there is nothing inherently “unsafe” about this. However, in general, very few guarantees can be given when passing a lambda to another method about what the called method expects about the lifetime of any captured variables.